# How can I get javadocs / groovydocs for groovy methods in an IntelliJ IDEA Grails project?

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, javadoc, groovydoc

When working in a Grails project, I don't get any useful javadocs / groovydocs for the GDK methods that groovy adds to things like collections. Is there a way to do this, or is this something IntelliJ IDEA just can't do?

Comment: It does actually look like whenever they implemented code completion for `DefaultGroovyMethods`, pulling in the javadoc was missed.

Comment: @mootinator - It looks for the doc, but I think it's just looking in the wrong way because it says it's looking in all of the doc locations I've configured (including the web api doc places)

Comment: Perhaps related: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/DefaultGroovyMethods-deprecated-td5710664.html

Answer (score 1):

Create global library groovy with javadocs pointing to `api` and `gapi` and add `groovy` global library to your grails module

```
sargis@sargis:~> ll $GROOVY_HOME/docs/html 
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 5 sargis users 4096 25 juil. 08:24 api
drwxr-xr-x 4 sargis users 4096 25 juil. 08:24 gapi
drwxr-xr-x 6 sargis users 4096 25 juil. 08:24 groovy-jdk
```